# Incorrect address on geocoding

Tags: geocoding, here-api

When converting Swedish addresses using here geocoding I get poor results. For example sending "Uppsala universitet", the oldest university in Sweden and well known throughout the world, into the engine it returns an address in Russia and not Sweden.. we have not seen this problem using Google geocoding. Please follow up with recommendations such as best practices.

Thanks

```
This is the request:

Request: https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=Uppsala%2Buniversitet&apiKey=eee

Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Университет СНТ, Кировский район, Северо-Западный федеральный округ, Россия
                    [id] => here:cm:namedplace:27706428
                    [resultType] => locality
                    [localityType] => district
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Университет СНТ, Кировский район, Северо-Западный федеральный округ, Россия
                            [countryCode] => RUS
                            [countryName] => Россия
                            [state] => Северо-Западный федеральный округ
                            [county] => Ленинградская область
                            [city] => Кировский район
                            [district] => Университет СНТ
                            [postalCode] => 187300
                        )

                    [position] => Array
                        (
                            [lat] => 59.76567
                            [lng] => 31.13737
                        )

                    [mapView] => Array
                        (
                            [west] => 31.13587
                            [south] => 59.76438
                            [east] => 31.13924
                            [north] => 59.76792
                        )

                    [scoring] => Array
                        (
                            [queryScore] => 0.61
                            [fieldScore] => Array
                                (
                                    [district] => 0.79
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Университет СНТ, Калининский район, Центральный федеральный округ, Россия
                    [id] => here:cm:namedplace:26899860
                    [resultType] => locality
                    [localityType] => district
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Университет СНТ, Калининский район, Центральный федеральный округ, Россия
                            [countryCode] => RUS
                            [countryName] => Россия
                            [state] => Центральный федеральный округ
                            [county] => Тверская область
                            [city] => Калининский район
                            [district] => Университет СНТ
                        )

                    [position] => Array
                        (
                            [lat] => 56.88779
                            [lng] => 35.99222
                        )

                    [mapView] => Array
                        (
                            [west] => 35.98932
                            [south] => 56.8874
                            [east] => 35.996
                            [north] => 56.89119
                        )

                    [scoring] => Array
                        (
                            [queryScore] => 0.61
                            [fieldScore] => Array
                                (
                                    [district] => 0.79
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Университет СНТ, Тосненский район, Северо-Западный федеральный округ, Россия
                    [id] => here:cm:namedplace:27706271
                    [resultType] => locality
                    [localityType] => district
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Университет СНТ, Тосненский район, Северо-Западный федеральный округ, Россия
                            [countryCode] => RUS
                            [countryName] => Россия
                            [state] => Северо-Западный федеральный округ
                            [county] => Ленинградская область
                            [city] => Тосненский район
                            [district] => Университет СНТ
                            [postalCode] => 187070
                        )

                    [position] => Array
                        (
                            [lat] => 59.19322
                            [lng] => 31.44631
                        )

                    [mapView] => Array
                        (
                            [west] => 31.43226
                            [south] => 59.19163
                            [east] => 31.45757
                            [north] => 59.19642
                        )

                    [scoring] => Array
                        (
                            [queryScore] => 0.61
                            [fieldScore] => Array
                                (
                                    [district] => 0.79
                                )

                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Университет-1 СНТ, Екатеринбург, Уральский федеральный округ, Россия
                    [id] => here:cm:namedplace:28294892
                    [resultType] => locality
                    [localityType] => district
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Университет-1 СНТ, Екатеринбург, Уральский федеральный округ, Россия
                            [countryCode] => RUS
                            [countryName] => Россия
                            [state] => Уральский федеральный округ
                            [county] => Свердловская область
                            [city] => Екатеринбург
                            [district] => Университет-1 СНТ
                            [postalCode] => 620000
                        )

                    [position] => Array
                        (
                            [lat] => 56.82014
                            [lng] => 60.4917
                        )

                    [mapView] => Array
                        (
                            [west] => 60.48843
                            [south] => 56.81566
                            [east] => 60.49345
                            [north] => 56.82024
                        )

                    [scoring] => Array
                        (
                            [queryScore] => 0.61
                            [fieldScore] => Array
                                (
                                    [district] => 0.73
                                )

                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Университет-2 СНТ, Элиста, Южный федеральный округ, Россия
                    [id] => here:cm:namedplace:26973643
                    [resultType] => locality
                    [localityType] => district
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Университет-2 СНТ, Элиста, Южный федеральный округ, Россия
                            [countryCode] => RUS
                            [countryName] => Россия
                            [state] => Южный федеральный округ
                            [county] => Республика Калмыкия
                            [city] => Элиста
                            [district] => Университет-2 СНТ
                        )

                    [position] => Array
                        (
                            [lat] => 46.32128
                            [lng] => 44.16565
                        )

                    [mapView] => Array
                        (
                            [west] => 44.15992
                            [south] => 46.32018
                            [east] => 44.17171
                            [north] => 46.32328
                        )

                    [scoring] => Array
                        (
                            [queryScore] => 0.61
                            [fieldScore] => Array
                                (
                                    [district] => 0.73
                                )

                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Uppsala, Uppsala län, Sverige
                    [id] => here:cm:namedplace:20298642
                    [resultType] => locality
                    [localityType] => city
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Uppsala, Uppsala län, Sverige
                            [countryCode] => SWE
                            [countryName] => Sverige
                            [state] => Uppsala län
                            [county] => Uppsala
                            [city] => Uppsala
                            [postalCode] => SE-753 41
                        )

                    [position] => Array
                        (
                            [lat] => 59.85862
                            [lng] => 17.64373
                        )

                    [mapView] => Array
                        (
                            [west] => 17.07893
                            [south] => 59.73083
                            [east] => 18.47498
                            [north] => 60.18991
                        )

                    [scoring] => Array
                        (
                            [queryScore] => 0.39
                            [fieldScore] => Array
                                (
                                    [city] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Can you please give the API request so we can be sure of the HERE service to reproduce it?

Comment: Yes I will return soon with the request.

Comment: Now I have the request and response posted

Comment: Thank you for reporting this. Our engineering team is looking into this and will get back to you soon.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport we still are waiting for feedback on best practise.